# Crystal Reports show current month as a 2 digit field

Tags: crystal-reports

I wonder if anyone could help on this please? I need to show the current month as a 2 digit field. IE 
January as 01
February as 02
March as 03
etc until
October as 10
November as 11
December as 12

The formula I am using is: ToText ("0"& Month(CurrentDate))
but shows January as 01.00 
ie need to remove the decimal point and the decimal places

Many thanks, Rob

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
ToText( CurrentDate, "MM")
```

Answer (score 0):

The ToText function will automatically convert the date you are supplying to whatever format you want.  You don't need to use the Month function.  Per the documentation, you just supply the date and the output format.  For the month, you use "MM".

```
ToText(CurrentDate, "MM")
```

According to the documention, these are the valid strings you can use

```
Pattern  Result
d        Numeric day of month without leading zero (1, 7, 31)
dd       Numeric day of month with leading zero (01, 07, 31)
ddd      Three day abbreviation of day of week (Mon, Sat)
dddd     Full name of day of week (Monday, Saturday)
M        Numeric month without leading zero (1, 7, 12)
MM       Numeric month with leading zero (01, 07, 12)
MMM      Three letter abbreviation of month (Jan, Feb, Mar)
MMMM     Full name of month (January, February, March)
yy       Last two digits of year (11, 14, 22)
yyyy     Full four digits of year (2011, 2014, 2022)
```

Comment: what about weeks? how to always show 2 digits (01,07,22)?

Answer (score 0):

To add to the above, if you need to return something like Mar-17 then:

totext({Command.DocDate},"MMM") + '-' + totext({Command.DocDate},"yy")